# Ruby - Ensure Syslog Gets Closed

Tags: ruby, syslog

Is it absolutely critical that I always close Syslog when I'm done using it? Is there a huge negative impact from not doing so?

If it turns out that I definitely need to, what's a good way to do it? I'm opening Syslog in my class constructor and I don't see a way to do class destructors in Ruby, and currently have something resembling this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @@log = Syslog.open("foo")
  end
end
```

I don't immediately see the place where the `Syslog.close` call should be, but what do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open method accepts a block.  Do something like this:

```
class Foo
  def do_something
    Syslog.open do
      # work with the syslog here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would calling the 'do_something' method then be much more expensive than just opening syslog once, using it as much as needed, and then closing it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're opening it as a class variable... so the proper way would be to do...

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @@log = Syslog.open("foo")
  end

  def Foo.finalize(id)
    @@log.close if @@log
  end
end
```

Though this is not necesssarily predictable or supported. It's the way to do it if you're going to keep the code the way you do.